# Android : Update widget when notification coming

Tags: android, notifications, widget

I'm working on a widget witch display the number of missing call, number of new sms, number of new mail and number of any notification. Like that following picture link :

https://1drv.ms/i/s!AnNwF6LmB2gQi34jxc_11yB703l8

But to avoid battery drain, is it possible to update widget only when a any notification is coming ? or I have to create a background service which looking for notification ?

Answer (score 0):

use  [notification listener service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems to be the good solution. (I'm working on Xamarin)

I have a MainActivity.cs, an AppWidget.cs and a NotificationService.cs (for NotificationListenerService).

Currently, my widget is updating when I create one, or every 30mn. My ListenerService could catch notification posting or removing. But I can't update my widget from the ListenerService. could you help me please ?

My update function in ListenerService is called when it catch post or remove :

```
    void UpdateWidget()
    {
        RemoteViews view = new RemoteViews(PackageName, Resource.Layout.Widget);
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.GetInstance(context);
        ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context.PackageName, Class.Name);
        appWidgetManager.UpdateAppWidget(thisWidget, view);
    }
```

And in my appwidget.cs, I have this function :

```
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        switch (intent.Action)
        {
            default:
                {
                    Log.Info("YotaWMNofifier", "** OnReceive received intent: {0}", intent.Action);
                }
                break;

            case AppWidgetManager.ActionAppwidgetUpdate:
                {
                    Log.Info("YotaWMNofifier", "** OnReceive received intent: Update widget");
                    WidgetUpdater(context);
                }
                break;

            case AppWidgetManager.ActionAppwidgetDisabled:
                {
                    Log.Info("YotaWMNofifier", "** OnReceive received intent: Delete last widget");
                }
                break;

            case AppWidgetManager.ActionAppwidgetEnabled:
                {
                    Log.Info("YotaWMNofifier", "** OnReceive received intent: Create widget");
                    WidgetUpdater(context);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

I never have the Log.info from the OnReceive function, but I have it from OnNotificationRemoved and OnNotificationPosted of service